# Change idle duration at runtime in AngularJS Ng-Idle

Tags: angularjs, ng-idle

I am using ng-idle to detect inactivity.

The `idleDuration` is set like so:

```
.config(function($idleProvider, $keepaliveProvider) {
            // configure $idle settings
            $idleProvider.idleDuration(5); // in seconds
            $idleProvider.warningDuration(5); // in seconds
            $keepaliveProvider.interval(2); // in seconds
        })
```

How can I change it at runtime in a controller or in a service?

It is possible to inject the `$idle` service like so:

```
.controller('EventsCtrl', function($scope, $idle)
```

Unforunately `$idle` does not have a property for changing the `idleDuration`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per v1.0.0, `Idle.setIdle()` can change the configuration value at any time.

Answer (score 1):

I know i'm answering late...

In older versions v1.0.0 Idle time cannot be change at the run-time, once it is initialized using **IdleProvider.idle(seconds)**.

But in version v1.0.0 he provided new api to change config value at rum-time using **Idle.setIdle(seconds)**

**Note: Seconds should be integer value. By default Idle time will be 20 mins**

Refernce https://github.com/HackedByChinese/ng-idle/wiki/Idle-and-Idleprovider

Comment: How can I change timeout in minutes instead of seconds?

Comment: For example if you want timeout for 50mins, change code to Idle.setIdle(50 * 60)